# Scheme, stopping my recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme

The function `firstnprimes` is supposed to return the first `n` primes. Arguments are `n` the number of primes, `nlist` a list from 2-m of integers. and `slist` is the solution list and is initially empty and is added to and reconstructed each call to firstnprimes.

It works by removing the first number from the list and then removing all multiples of that number from `nlist` with `listminusnonprimes`; which I know works. The problem is that I can't control this action, I figure for each pass if `slist`'s length was equal to the number of primes you want then you're done.

Code:

```
(define firstnprimes
  (lambda (n nlist slist)
   (let ((slist (cons (car nlist) slist)))
    (if (zero? n)
        slist
        (firstnprimes (- n 1) (listMinusNonprimes (car nlist) (car nlist) nlist) slist)))))


(define listminusnonprimes
     (lambda (num d lst)
       (if (null? lst)
           '()
           (if (= d (car lst))
               (listminusnonprimes num (+ num d) (cdr lst))
               (cons (car lst) (listminusnonprimes num d (cdr lst)))))))
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Termination of the recursion?  Looks fine from a quick glance.  Also, it seems you don't need `n` except for the length, which means that you should be able to decrement `n` on every recursive call and then just check if `n` is equal to or less than zero instead of computing the list length again and again.

Comment: ok so each call to firsnprimes on the last line i remove one from n and check if it is zero on the if statement. good looks. Though I end up with every numbers counting by 2 up to n for my output (still).

Comment: I guess can anyone see the problem

Comment: @BumSkeeter You still need to decrease `n` by one on the last line, also what does `listMinusNonprimes` do? Why are you passing `(car nlist)` twice to it?

Comment: listminusnonprimes removes multiples first input number, increasing by the second. so "2 2 list" will remove first 2 from the list and then 2+2 from the list and then 2+2+2, etc. also I changed the code so that is checks to see if n is zero, because we add to the list by one each time we can decrement n by one each time.

Comment: I have added listminusnonprimes to the example code above.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `listminusnonprimes` is wrong. Imagine the call `(listminusnonprimes 3 3 '(3 5 7 9 11 ...))` (as this would happen after you remove all multiples of `2`). Now `3` is removed, and recursively you call `(listminusnonprimes 6 3 '(5 7 9 11 ...))`, but `6` is not there, so the call does nothing and the result is `(3 5 7 9 11 ...)`.

I would suggest implementing this function using the mod operation.

Comment: Like so? ;Returns a list with nonprimes based off num removed
(define lmnp 
  (lambda (n list)
    (if (null? list)
        '()
        (if (= (modulo (car list) n) 0)
            (lmnp n (cdr list))
            (cons (car list) (lmnp n (cdr list)))))))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `(let ((slist (cons (car nlist) slist)))`. Also, use append instead of cons as shown

```
(define firstnprimes
  (lambda (n nlist slist)
    (if (zero? n)
        slist
        (firstnprimes (- n 1) (listminusnonprimes (car nlist) (car nlist) nlist) (append slist (list (car nlist)))))))
```

So,

```
(firstnprimes 2 '(2 4 7 9 21 36) '()) => '(2 7)
(firstnprimes 3 '(2 4 7 9 21 36) '()) => '(2 7 9)
```

Lots of problems with your implementation though. First, the list has to be in increasing order. Also, the list has to start with a prime number. Also, the number of prime numbers in the `nlist` has to be less than or equal to `n`. 
`(firstnprimes 4 '(2 4 7 9 21 36) '()) =>  '(2 7 9 21)` which is wrong

Here is a slightly better implementation of your concept.

```
(define firstnprimes
  (lambda (n nlist slist)
    (if (or (zero? n) (null? nlist))
        slist
        (firstnprimes (- n 1) (listminusnonprimes (car nlist) (car nlist) nlist) (append slist (list (car nlist)))))))


(define listminusnonprimes
     (lambda (num d lst)
       (if (null? lst)
           '()
           (if (< d (car lst))
               (listminusnonprimes num (+ num d) lst)
               (if (= d (car lst))
                   (listminusnonprimes num (+ num d) (cdr lst))
                   (cons (car lst) (listminusnonprimes num (+ num d) (cdr lst))))))))
```

Now,

```
(firstnprimes 2 '(2 4 7 9 21 36) '()) => '(2 7)
(firstnprimes 3 '(2 4 7 9 21 36) '()) => '(2 7 9)
(firstnprimes 4 '(2 4 7 9 21 36) '()) => '(2 7 9)
```

But the first element still has to be prime though